# MongoDB синхронизация двух баз данных

Tags: mongodb, архитектура

Мне нужно что бы у меня **синхронизировлись две базы данных**. И в них записи добавлялись синхронно. **Есть ли решения для Mongo DB**. В этой сфере?

**У MySQL точно есть.** Поэтому и спрашиваю.

### Зачем мне это нужно?

Просто много cron данных должен будет обрабатывать.
И да я знаю что могу построить два микросервиса. Но хотелось бы найти более аккуратное решение.

Comment: Не совсем понял,что Вам надо, но может эта инфа поможет - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/

Comment: @Дмытрык спасибо именно то и искал!

Answer (score 0):

MongoShake https://github.com/alibaba/MongoShake
Примеры сценариев применения MongoShake

1. Асинхронная репликация данных между кластерами MongoDB устраняет необходимость в операциях двойной записи.
2. Зеркальное резервное копирование данных между кластерами MongoDB (текущая версия с открытым исходным кодом 1.0 имеет ограниченную поддержку)
3. Анализ журнала в автономном режиме
4. Журнал подписки
5. Маршрутизация данных. В соответствии с потребностями бизнеса, в сочетании с механизмом подписки на журнал и фильтрацией, вы можете получить интересующие вас данные для достижения функции маршрутизации данных.
6. Синхронизация кеша. Записывайте результаты анализа, узнайте, какой Cache можно исключить, какой Cache можно предварительно загрузить, и запустите обновление Cache в обратном порядке.
7. Журнал на основе кластерного мониторинга